# Gridview All Data is one line

Tags: asp.net, gridview, line, row

I have `Gridview` but some daha is two or three line. (more than one)

[image]

How can i show all daha is one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give width to your columns.

Take a look at [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t98528-set-the-width-of-datagrid-column.html) and [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/datagrid/article.php/c9603)

Comment: This is resize and for columns. I ask how can i show every data one line.

Comment: You want to have more than 1 rows of data and you want every row to be 1 line as I understand? And to do this, you need to increase width of your columns.